# Como Instanciar uma classe PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Geralmente para instanciar e utilizar uma classe no meu projeto, utilizo:

```
include ('arquivo_que_contem_a_classe.php'); 
$obj = new obj(); 
$obj->nomedafunction();
```

Mas hoje precisei de uma classe já pronta baixada do github via composer, que criou alguns diretórios e um arquivo autoload.php.

No exemplo de uso dessa classe, pde pra utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
$obj = new \dir1\dir1\dir3([
  'var1'        =>  'var1', 
  'var2'    =>  'var2', 
  'var3'   =>  'var3', 
  'var4'    =>  'var4']); 

$executa = $obj->nomedafunction();
```

Não entendi o método de instanciar essa classe. Não sei como pesquisar isso no Google, por isso to aqui pedindo uma força pra me explicar como funciona.

Obs: Os códigos acima são apenas exemplos.

Comment: O que você não entendeu?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não entendi pq não tem um include do arquivo que contem a classe e o que seria esses "\dir1\dir1\dir3".

Comment: Deve ter em algum lugar. Ou a classe está definida logo acima do código, não existe milagre. Isso seria `namespace`.

Comment: O autoload do Composer se encarregará de fazer o include do arquivo para você. Basta pesquisar por "PHP autoload" ou mais especificamente PSR 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é um recurso que se chama namespace

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.php

Serve para separar suas classes de forma lógica, mas elas precisam ser "includeds" do mesmo jeito ... mas o autoload do composer já faz isso pra ti, sendo necessário apenas referenciá-las dessa forma